How can I ensure line breaks inside block quotes are rendered as entered in the markup?
At least in the editor preview, this doesn't render linebreaks:
> foo
> bar
> baz


foo
bar
baz

Screenshot: 
Is this a problem of my browser? Or something else? On StackEdit it works as expected!

Put two white-space characters at the end of a line.

Wow, thank you! How come, is this a rule of Markdown?

There's nothing special about these lines being in blockquotes. The same thing would happen if the lines were not in blockquotes. This is just one of the ways that Markdown works. A single linebreak in the source text is considered an extension of the previous line, unless there's formatting that indicates that it's not a continuation (i.e., continuing the previous line is the default).

Ah, thank you! It was just confusing that StackEdit behaves differently, so StackEdit apparently is not pure MD.

The Linebreaks section of the Markdown help says:

End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak

> baz  
> bar

Which renders as:

baz
bar


Or put a \ at the end of the line.
